# Is there a way to parametrise an AR1 structure for a binomial gamm in mgcv with a use-availability design with correlated 1s and uncorrelated 0s?

Tags: r, binary-data, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I am modelling the habitat preference of a species in a use-availability design using the mgcv package in R. The data consist of telemetry observations during multiple foraging trips for multiple individuals with some environmental covariate values. I therefore have presences (telemetry locations) and control points (randomly generated data points that provide a sample of the background habitat) to quantify habitat use in the context of what is available to the animal. So the response variable for my model is binary 0/1; 0 for "available" points (control points / pseudo-absences) and 1 for "used" (presences / telemetry points). For each presence there are 5 control points that are tied to that presence (i.e. they have the same timestamp and information relating to the individual, but different covariate values). The data are weighted in the model such that each set of 5 control points contributes the same as one presence. I would like to model this in a bam as I have a problem with residual autocorrelation, and it allows me to include an AR1 structure in a mixed effects model with a binomial error structure (see this post: [Is there a way to include an autocorrelation structure in the gam function of mgcv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74241467/is-there-a-way-to-include-an-autocorrelation-structure-in-the-gam-function-of-mg)). In this case, each trip would be a separate time series, and individual would be a random effect term, implemented using the bs="re" structure in mgcv. However, I am wondering if there is a way to code the AR1 structure such that only correlation between the presences is considered, and not the control points, since I would not expect the randomly generated data to be correlated. I have been using the start_event function from itsadug to parametrise the time series and set rho for the AR1 structure (see here: [https://rdrr.io/cran/itsadug/f/vignettes/acf.Rmd](https://stackoverflow.com)).

Here is a reproducible example of the problem, adapted from the code in the itsadug vignette. In my data Subject would be the individual animal ID, Trial would be the foraging trip ID, and Y would be some environmental covariate:

```
library(itsadug)
library(mgcv)
library(tidyverse)
data(simdat)

used <- as_tibble(simdat) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Subject, Trial, Time, Y)

#generate 5 control points with random Y values for each presence
#set a column to code 1 for presences and 0s for control points
#add weights such that each group of 5 control points contributes the same as a presence
control <- used %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = 5)) 
control <- control %>% 
  mutate(Y = rnorm(dim(control)[1], summary(used$Y)[5], summary(used$Y)[6]),
         Presence = 0,
         Weight = 1/5)
used <- used %>% 
  mutate(Presence = 1,
         Weight = 1)

#merge the presences and control points and order
dat <- bind_rows(used, control) %>% 
  arrange(Subject, Trial, Time, rev(Presence))
dat$Trial <- as_factor(dat$Trial)

#Transform to dataframe for itsadug function below
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

#add the time series information for the AR1 structure
dat <- start_event(dat, column = "Time", event = c("Subject", "Trial"), label.event = "Event")

#First fit the model with no correlation structure
m1 <- bam(Presence ~ s(Y) + s(Subject, bs = 're'), data = dat, family = "binomial" (link = logit), 
          method = "fREML", discrete = TRUE, weights = Weight)
acf_resid(m1)

#set rho to lag1 of presences based on fitted model above
r1 <- acf(resid(m1), plot=FALSE)$acf[7]
m1AR1 <- bam(Presence ~ s(Y) + s(Subject, bs = 're'), data = dat, family = "binomial" (link = logit), 
             method = "fREML", discrete = TRUE, weights = Weight, rho = r1, AR.start = dat$start.event)
acf_resid(m1AR1)
```

PROBLEM: How to set the start.event values for control points such that they are not considered in the AR1 structure. Changing them to NA leads to them being excluded from the model fit. Changing them all to FALSE retains them in the AR1 structure and appears to make very little difference to the residuals.

If there is no way to circumvent this problem with the coding of the AR1 structure, is there an alternative approach I could use here? In the past I have thinned the data, but this is not appealing as I could potentially be losing important signal.

Comment: Why not try to model the temporal component? I appreciate that a `s(Time)` or `s(as.factor(Time), bs = "re")` might not get very fine scale temporal effects, but it might be enough. Maybe also check out the *ppgam* package, which I think avoids the need for the pseudo absences in the response data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Gavin. I have tried the temporal smooth options and this does not appear to have enough of an effect on the residuals in my case... I have not tried a point process approach though, so I will investigate this. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you try `s(Time) + s(Timef, bs = "re")` where `Timef` is the time variable coerced to a factor? You can also include an AR(1) through the MRF basis; maybe you can code that the way you want, to make the control points have no neighbours?

Comment: Yes I did try that exact formulation and it only resulted in a very slight reduction in residual autocorrelation. I'll take a look at the Markov Random Field approach - it is no something I have ever tried. Thanks again for the suggestions!